# How to get request and response header in Savon SOAP request with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, savon

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://localhost:8080/soap_test/services/StationDirectorySoapServerPort?wsdl")
```

using this call I do request SOAP service

```
client.operations

@message ="xml input"
response = client.call :get_state, xml: @message
```

how to get Header of request and response from Savon client and response object ?

Answer (score 0):

with this request

```
response = client.call :get_state, xml: @message
```

you can call:

```
response.header
```

and

```
response.body
```

to get the answer from server..